# How to avoid clobbering files when creating a tar archive

Tags: tar, confirm, overwrite

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535508/overwritten-file-with-tar) notes that it is possible to overwrite files when creating a tar archive, and I'm trying to see how to avoid that situation.

Normally, I'd use file roller, but the version installed is playing up a bit (using 1.1 Gb of memory), and I'm not the system administrator.

I looked at --confirmation and --interactive, but that only asks me if I want to add file x to the archive, not whether I want to overwrite an existing file. For example,

```
tar --interactive -czvf innocent_text_file.txt foo*
```

Will ask me about each file, but is perfectly happy to overwrite innocent_text_file.txt

Is there any switch that acts like -i for cp?

**Note** I am asking about creating an archive, not extracting an archive.

**Clarification** What I'm worried about is accidentally doing something like this

```
tar -czvf * #Don't do this!
```

which would overwrite the first file listed in the glob. To avoid it, I want tar to complain if the first file mentioned already exists, like

```
cp -i * #Don't do this!
```

would check if it would cause you to overwrite an existing file.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly I believe this should to the trick:

tar -cv * | gzip > myfile.tgz

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should do the trick

> -k, --keep-old-files
>                 keep existing files; don’t overwrite them from archive

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. innocent_text_file.txt gets overwritten when the erroneous tar command for archive *creation* is given.

Comment: The --keep-old-files option is for extracting only

Answer (score 0):

What about "u" (update) instead of "c" (create)?  e.g., tar -uzvf

That should only add (and overwrite) the file if it's newer than the one in the archive.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

These are overwrite controls while **extracting** from a tar.

```
Overwrite control:

-k, --keep-old-files  don't replace existing files when extracting
  --keep-newer-files  don't replace existing files that are newer than
                      their archive copies
  --no-overwrite-dir  preserve metadata of existing directories
  --overwrite         overwrite existing files when extracting
  --overwrite-dir     overwrite metadata of existing directories when
                      extracting (default)
  --recursive-unlink  empty hierarchies prior to extracting directory
  --remove-files      remove files after adding them to the archive
```

But, you refer to `cp -i` and `tar c` operations for reference.
Which implies you are interested in **updating** an archive that does not 
overwrite an existing copy in the tar with a new version. I suspect that control is not directly available with tar.
I also wonder at the need for such a scheme.

However, one way to go about this would be as follows.
Since, you are worried about overwrites into the archive,
we safely assume you have an existing partial tar of the directory (say `files.tar`).

```
cd base/dir/to/be/tarred 
tar tf path/to/files.tar | sort > archived-files.lst
find . -type f | sort > files.lst
diff archived-files.lst files.lst | grep "^>" | cut -c 3- > new.lst
tar uf -T new.lst
```

Note that this `update` works only on uncompressed archives.
So, if your archive is compressed gunzip/bunzip2 it as appropriate before this sequence.
and, then re-compress it at the end.

Comment: I'm asking about archive creation, not extraction.

Comment: Yes, I figured, but it sounds like an unusual requirement. You really want to retain the first copy of the file in the archive even if its is modified/updated in the live directory?

Comment: I've added a clarification at the end of the original question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: About `clobbering` existing files by mistakenly missing out the target archive name on the command line, I recollect `tar` used to avoid doing that when the `c` option for create was used. However, a quick check on my local Cygwin did no do that. I am surprised.

Comment: As an aside, the Unix command prompt is a holy place. More so when you are root/admin. It does not forgive and helps you forget. I remember the resident roots at our university used to categorically avoid the root shell on drunk late evenings!